# Azure Data Factory pipeline fails when Self-Hosted Integration runtime loads ORC file: OutOfMemory Exception, Heap size

Tags: java, azure, heap-memory, azure-data-factory

I am facing at the moment a problem when trying to load ORC files from Azure Data Factory. When the file is too big the ADF pipeline complains that our Self Hosted Integration Runtime fails with OutOfMemory Exception due to the fact that the Java Max Heap size is too small to complete the load.

Already tried different solution like increasing the Heap size through Environment variables or even keys in the Registry (kind of a hack). The VM with the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime has more than 100GB RAM.

Still failing though because it seems the values keep being overridden with "default" values when the Integration Runtime is queried from ADF. Any idea by any chance?

```
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred when invoking java, message: java.nio.BufferOverflowException:Unable to retrieve Java exception..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.OrcTransferPlugin,StackTrace= at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcDeserializer.<GetRows>d__42.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.DeserializeControllerBase.GetEstimatedRowSize()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcDeserializeController..ctor(DataTable targetSchema, IEnumerable`1 streams, OrcFormatSetting settings, IErrorRowOutput errorRowOutput)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcSerializer.Deserialize(TransferStream stream)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.DeserializationStageProcessor.<Deserialize>d__14.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.TypeConversionStageProcessor.<CreateDataReader>d__5.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SerializationStageProcessor.<Serialize>d__11.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.BinarySinkStageProcessor.<PopulateStreamName>d__10.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.MultipartWriteSink.ConsumeStreams(IEnumerable`1 streams),''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,StackTrace= at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.Bridge.BaseObjectBridge.CallObject[TEnum](TEnum methodEnum, jValue[] args)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.Bridge.Orc.OrcBatchReaderBridge.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcDeserializer.<GetRows>d__42.MoveNext(),'
Job ID: daee1a1d-b880-ecb2-e56c-a59397547668
Log ID: Warning        
TraceComponentId: TransferClientLibrary
TraceMessageId: TasksCoordinatorFatalErrorCallback
@logId: Warning
jobId: daee1a1d-b880-ecb2-e56c-a59397547668
activityId: c643b611-8356-4f49-b6d6-e87ea50670e5
eventId: TasksCoordinatorFatalErrorCallback
message: 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred when invoking java, message: java.nio.BufferOverflowException:Unable to retrieve Java exception..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.OrcTransferPlugin,StackTrace= at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcDeserializer.<GetRows>d__42.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.DeserializeControllerBase.GetEstimatedRowSize()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcDeserializeController..ctor(DataTable targetSchema, IEnumerable`1 streams, OrcFormatSetting settings, IErrorRowOutput errorRowOutput)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcSerializer.Deserialize(TransferStream stream)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.DeserializationStageProcessor.<Deserialize>d__14.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.TypeConversionStageProcessor.<CreateDataReader>d__5.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SerializationStageProcessor.<Serialize>d__11.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.BinarySinkStageProcessor.<PopulateStreamName>d__10.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.MultipartWriteSink.ConsumeStreams(IEnumerable`1 streams),''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,StackTrace= at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.Bridge.BaseObjectBridge.CallObject[TEnum](TEnum methodEnum, jValue[] args)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.Bridge.Orc.OrcBatchReaderBridge.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.OrcDeserializer.<GetRows>d__42.MoveNext(),'
```

Comment: After increasing the heap size, did you restart the self hosted IR?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT yes, I had direct contact with Microsoft and it turned out to be a problem on their side eventually. Will create an answer for this.

Comment: Glad you found the workaround, thank you for this information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft found a bug on their own side. When loading an .orc file this kind of error can occur if the .orc file contains **char** or **varchar** column types.
Converting them all to **String** type fixed this error.
It's been recognized by Microsoft, it's on the Azure Data Factory side and will take about 6 months from now to be fixed.